# What happens if I set the pool_connections parameter to 0 for request sessions?

Tags: python, http, session, python-requests, connection-pooling

```
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=1))
s.get('https://www.baidu.com')
```

- In the above code what will happen if I set the pool_connections to 0 instead of 1?
- Will it work normally like requests.get() method?
- Also if it works like requests.get() then can I mount pool_connections=0 for some specific domain prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, upon setting pool_connections = 0 it will give the following error

*requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='baidu.com', port=443): Pool is closed.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).